# Why function's stack memory can be overwritten by calling a function without overflow behavior?

Tags: c, assembly

In CSAPP [attack lab](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/labs.html), the [hand-out](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/attacklab.pdf) of level3 said:
"When functions hexmatch and strncmp are called, they push data onto the stack, overwriting
portions of memory that held the buffer used by getbuf. As a result, you will need to be careful where you place the string representation of your cookie."

I see it and pass the lab, but I literally don't understand why the stack memory of a function can be destroyed by calling a function without overflow behavior.
The 40 bytes stack memory held in 'getbuf' seems to be overwritten after there is a code injection to switch the execution flow to 'touch3'. More accurately, after the 'hexmatch' and 'strncmp' are called.

```
00000000004017a8 <getbuf>:
  4017a8:   48 83 ec 28             sub    $0x28,%rsp
  4017ac:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
  4017af:   e8 8c 02 00 00          call   401a40 <Gets>
  4017b4:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  4017b9:   48 83 c4 28             add    $0x28,%rsp
  4017bd:   c3                      ret    
  4017be:   90                      nop
  4017bf:   90                      nop
000000000040184c <hexmatch>:
  40184c:   41 54                   push   %r12
  40184e:   55                      push   %rbp
  40184f:   53                      push   %rbx
  401850:   48 83 c4 80             add    $0xffffffffffffff80,%rsp
  401854:   41 89 fc                mov    %edi,%r12d
  401857:   48 89 f5                mov    %rsi,%rbp
  40185a:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
  401861:   00 00 
  401863:   48 89 44 24 78          mov    %rax,0x78(%rsp)
  401868:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40186a:   e8 41 f5 ff ff          call   400db0 <random@plt>
  40186f:   48 89 c1                mov    %rax,%rcx
  401872:   48 ba 0b d7 a3 70 3d    movabs $0xa3d70a3d70a3d70b,%rdx
  401879:   0a d7 a3 
  40187c:   48 f7 ea                imul   %rdx
  40187f:   48 01 ca                add    %rcx,%rdx
  401882:   48 c1 fa 06             sar    $0x6,%rdx
  401886:   48 89 c8                mov    %rcx,%rax
  401889:   48 c1 f8 3f             sar    $0x3f,%rax
  40188d:   48 29 c2                sub    %rax,%rdx
  401890:   48 8d 04 92             lea    (%rdx,%rdx,4),%rax
  401894:   48 8d 04 80             lea    (%rax,%rax,4),%rax
  401898:   48 c1 e0 02             shl    $0x2,%rax
  40189c:   48 29 c1                sub    %rax,%rcx
  40189f:   48 8d 1c 0c             lea    (%rsp,%rcx,1),%rbx
  4018a3:   45 89 e0                mov    %r12d,%r8d
  4018a6:   b9 e2 30 40 00          mov    $0x4030e2,%ecx
  4018ab:   48 c7 c2 ff ff ff ff    mov    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rdx
  4018b2:   be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
  4018b7:   48 89 df                mov    %rbx,%rdi
  4018ba:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4018bf:   e8 ac f5 ff ff          call   400e70 <__sprintf_chk@plt>
  4018c4:   ba 09 00 00 00          mov    $0x9,%edx
  4018c9:   48 89 de                mov    %rbx,%rsi
  4018cc:   48 89 ef                mov    %rbp,%rdi
  4018cf:   e8 cc f3 ff ff          call   400ca0 <strncmp@plt>
  4018d4:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  4018d6:   0f 94 c0                sete   %al
  4018d9:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
  4018dc:   48 8b 74 24 78          mov    0x78(%rsp),%rsi
  4018e1:   64 48 33 34 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rsi
  4018e8:   00 00 
  4018ea:   74 05                   je     4018f1 <hexmatch+0xa5>
  4018ec:   e8 ef f3 ff ff          call   400ce0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
  4018f1:   48 83 ec 80             sub    $0xffffffffffffff80,%rsp
  4018f5:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  4018f6:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4018f7:   41 5c                   pop    %r12
  4018f9:   c3                      ret    

00000000004018fa <touch3>:
  4018fa:   53                      push   %rbx
  4018fb:   48 89 fb                mov    %rdi,%rbx
  4018fe:   c7 05 d4 2b 20 00 03    movl   $0x3,0x202bd4(%rip)        # 6044dc <vlevel>
  401905:   00 00 00 
  401908:   48 89 fe                mov    %rdi,%rsi
  40190b:   8b 3d d3 2b 20 00       mov    0x202bd3(%rip),%edi        # 6044e4 <cookie>
  401911:   e8 36 ff ff ff          call   40184c <hexmatch>
  401916:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  401918:   74 23                   je     40193d <touch3+0x43>
  40191a:   48 89 da                mov    %rbx,%rdx
  40191d:   be 38 31 40 00          mov    $0x403138,%esi
  401922:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  401927:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40192c:   e8 bf f4 ff ff          call   400df0 <__printf_chk@plt>
  401931:   bf 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%edi
  401936:   e8 52 03 00 00          call   401c8d <validate>
  40193b:   eb 21                   jmp    40195e <touch3+0x64>
  40193d:   48 89 da                mov    %rbx,%rdx
  401940:   be 60 31 40 00          mov    $0x403160,%esi
  401945:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  40194a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  40194f:   e8 9c f4 ff ff          call   400df0 <__printf_chk@plt>
  401954:   bf 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%edi
  401959:   e8 f1 03 00 00          call   401d4f <fail>
  40195e:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  401963:   e8 d8 f4 ff ff          call   400e40 <exit@plt>
```

Comment: By that time `getbuf` already finished, its memory is freed and legally reused by the other functions called.

Comment: Referring to memory that has been freed/released is a logic error.  A function shouldn't return the address of a local array, because that local memory is released immediately upon return, leaving the caller with a reference to deallocated memory.

Comment: It is also a logic error to use memory newly allocated without initialization.

Answer (score 5):

The stack grows downwards and data is written upward.

When `getbuf` is called the stack pointer has a definite value, let's call it *sp0*.
`getbuff` then grows the stack by 0x30 bytes: 0x8 with its return address and 0x28 with `sub rsp, 0x28`. The stack pointer is now at *sp0 - 0x30*. Your input is copied at this address upward (*sp-0x30*, *sp-0x2f*, *sp-0x2e*, ...).
When `getbuf` returns, the stack is shrunk back to *sp0* but this is not a destructive operation, the data is still there. The shrinking is done with an `add`.
The red zone will also guarantee that no external event will overwrite this data.

Remember: The input data is at
*sp0-0x30* and continues upward, the stack pointer is at *sp0*, 0x30 bytes above the data, and move downward.

Lately, `touch3` and `hexmatch` are called. When this happens the stack pointer is at *sp0* and both these functions can push data and move the stack pointer down towards *sp0-0x30*, where your input string starts.
If these functions end up pushing too much data on the stack they will reach your string.

```
| sp0        | <-- The stack pointer before touch3 is here
|            | 
|            |    | direction of successive push on the stack
|            |    V 
|            |
|            |    ^
|            |    | direction of successive chars in the string
|            |
| sp0 - 0x30 | <-- Your string starts here.
```

If the string will be overwritten depends on its length and the exact calling sequence and the code executed.